# How do I write a bash script to automate setting up ufw rules using docker-machine?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-machine

I have a shell script that looks like this:

```
echo "======> setting up firewall rules for $1 ..."   
docker-machine ssh $1 \
echo "y" | sudo ufw --force enable \
&& sudo ufw default deny incoming \
&& sudo ufw allow 22/tcp \
&& sudo ufw allow 2376/tcp \
&& sudo ufw allow 2377/tcp \
&& sudo ufw allow 7946/tcp \
&& sudo ufw allow 7946/udp \
&& sudo ufw allow 4789/udp \
&& sudo ufw reload \
&& sudo systemctl restart docker
```

The logging info after running each ufw command says "Skipping adding existing rule" even though this is a brand new instance. I am able to manually ssh into the Docker machine instance and run the same command with no trouble. How do I write a bash script to automate setting up ufw rules using docker-machine?

Comment: Can't test it right now, but if `docker-machine ssh` is similar to `ssh`, you should wrap the complete command that follows with single quotes, like: `docker-machine ssh $1 'echo y | sudo ufw .... && .... '`. As you have it right now, only `echo` is executed in docker, and all the other commands on your host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`docker-machine ssh`](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/ssh/) command behaves similarly to the standard `ssh` command, namely it accepts the commands to run remotely.

In your example, however, **shell operators like `|` and `&&` take precedence**, i.e. they terminate the list of commands/arguments that the `docker-machine ssh` receives.

One way of fixing this is to quote the list of commands you wish for `docker-machine ssh` to receive, for example like this:

```
$ docker-machine ssh $1 \
'echo "y" | sudo ufw --force enable \
&& sudo ufw default deny incoming \
&& sudo ufw allow 22/tcp ... '
```

Another option is to escape all shell operators (`\|` and `\&\&`, even `\(`, `\{`, `\;`, etc).